# Heroku can't see config folder; why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, bash, heroku

although config folder is committed, heroku dosen't see it ..
when I do `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get this error:

```
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- /app/config/application
```

I tried to test it like this:

```
$ heroku run bash -a myapp
~ $ ls config
ls: cannot access config: No such file or directory
```

although I am sure config folder is committed and pushed, can some one help me ?

here is the git status:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .gitignore~
#   modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force another git push to your remote heroku repository. There were some git push errors on Heroku today. See http://status.heroku.com

Comment: I tried to force push like this: git push heroku master -f, but ,I get a result: Everything up-to-date, is this the correct way to force git push ?

Comment: make a change to some file, do a local commit, and do another push to Heroku.

Comment: I tried to make changes to boot.rb and application.rb, committed, and did another push, but, I have the same error ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not the `application.rb` file that it can't find? Can you try:

```
$ heroku run bash -a myapp
~ $ ls -al /app/config
```

Comment: yes, here is what I get:
ls: cannot access /app/config: No such file or directory

Comment: Your rake output suggests it's trying to load application.rb from inside the /app/config folder whilst in Rails it should be at the same level of the app directory ie /config/application.rb - does the app boot locally?